# No WiFi from Gnome GUI, can see in Terminal

Tags: wireless, gnome

I've come across an interesting problem where I am unable to see any wireless networks (or manage my wireless connections) from the user interface (Gnome 42), but I am both connected to the internet and able to manage this connection from the terminal.

For context, I installed Linux (server version - Ubuntu 22.04 LTS) a few months ago to get comfortable with the terminal before I moved to it as my daily driver. I added Gnome 42 a few weeks ago and have been using the wireless network I initially added when I did the server setup.

Is there anything that could cause this?

Further, I'm also unable to switch networks from the terminal - if I use `nmcli dev wifi connect NETWORKNAME password PASSWORD`, I get an error - `No network with SSID 'NETWORKNAME'`. I double checked the wireless network names with `iwlist wlp4so c`, so I know the ESSID is correct

That said, I'm unsure if this is related, or a separate issue to the initial one - I'm quite comfortable with working on my own machine (making new files, changing permissions, troubleshooting non-network related issues, etc.), but I'm quite new to troubleshooting network issues.

Comment: Is Network Manager installed? Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Yes - confirmed that it is both installed and up to date - as are all packages on my machine.

Comment: When you click the Network Manager icon, do you see your network? Can you click on it and try to connect?

Comment: No wifi networks show up anywhere on desktop settings - it says I'm not connected to any networks, nor are any networks detected. That said, if I try to do it from the terminal, it picks up my current network, but won't allow me to change to another network it supposedly detects.

Comment: Please edit your question to show: `cat /etc/network/interfaces` and also: `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml`